# How to replace an attribute in dojo Postcreate

Tags: javascript, dojo, widget

I am trying to replace a value coming from backend to use a new value I am creating.

This is the function in the PostCreate

```
    _setTagName: function () {
            var Tag = this._TagName();
           console.log(Tag);
       if (Tag != "") {
             this.Tag.title.value=Tag;
 }*/
        },
```

I do see the console.log prints the new tag which I am creating in another function. Wondering why it is not working when I assign its value to replace Tag.title. If better how can I use the Tag directly on my templated html.

For now the html looks like this

```
           <div>
<a  href="${Tag.url}" data-dojo-attach-point="tagNode">${Tag.title}</a><br />
```

Comment: I tried this and it worked using domAttr.set(this.tagNode,"innerHTML",Tag); Not sure if this is the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it worked using domAttr.set(this.tagNode,"innerHTML",Tag);